# Power Query - how to separate values, and add them to rows

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

How to separate values, and add them to rows? using Power Query

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another options is using `Table1` as source:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),
    SelectAllColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Transposed Table", SelectAllColumns, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Split Column by Delimiter")
in
    #"Transposed Table1"
```

[image]

[Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/-pVNpRucitk)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input table is named Table1, you have a header row labeled "a" and "b", and you want to split on ", " then my method seems to work : 
(a) delete b and split a then add index (b) delete a and split b then add index (c) combine parts a and b (d) choose index column and unpivot other columns to delete nulls (e) choose index column and pivot to combine the parts (f) transposes entire table to get back to original row/column view

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"a"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"b", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "b"),
#"Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"b"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns1", {{"a", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "a"),
#"Index2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter2", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Consolidated" = #"Index" & #"Index2",
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Consolidated, {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Index", type text}}), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Index", type text}})[Index]), "Index", "Value"),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Pivoted Column"),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]) 
in #"Promoted Headers"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvrUT.jpg